# Linear Programming constraint confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

I have no idea how to write this constraint "Due to popularity of laptops, ...need to produce at least twice as many laptops than desktops and servers combined" in order to solve it on Excel with Solver so X,Y,Z need to be on LHS and then a number on RHS. X= nbr of computers, Y= nbr of desktops and W= nbr of servers. I found X >= 2Y + 2W but I need all the letters on the left and a number thats not 0 on the right. I'm very confused... thank you! I'm not allowed to post pictures by the website

Comment: Why does the constraint $x - 2y - 2w \geq 0$ not pass as a valid constraint? If this is Excel specific you might be better off asking on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: ohh right! actually I think this might work on Excel as well. Thank you!!